# Can not receive WhatsApp messages unless I open the app

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, huawei, 9.0-pie, background-process

I have a Huawei P20 Lite with Android 9, EMUI 9.1.0 and WhatsApp 2.19.253, which is the latest version.

As I wrote in the title, I can't receive WhatsApp messages, after many hours of researching I didn't find any solution for my problem. This is the first time I face whit this problem, because I managed and configured variues P20 Lite but none of them gave me that headache.

The things which I did:

- Turn on every single option for WhatsApp's notifications;
- Uninstall the application and install it again;
- Remove the app from the battery optimization process;
- Clear the cache;
- Enabled automatic start, secondary start and running in background, following this steps Settings -> Battery -> app launch -> 3 vertical dots -> manage manually;
- No limit for internet traffic and allow background data, following Settings -> networks and wireless -> data usage -> select WhatsApp -> enabled the varius option.

Any idea or solution for this problem?

EDIT

When I send a message from my phone to this P20 Lite, on the message appears only 1 tick, such as the P20 is disconnected from wifi/mobile data, but the wifi is enabled and connected, the same behaviour with mobile data.

Comment: Have you disabled background data for Google Play Services? This service is used for notifying Whatsapp of new messages. See this question and it's answers for details: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216714

Comment: @Robert No, the only things which I did, are wrote in the answer

Comment: Does your phone never receives messages when the screen is off or is there just a long delay. Let someone send you a message and leave the phone alone for may be 30 minutes.

Comment: @Robert Yes, the phone receives messages when the screen is lock, but after 5-10 minutes WhatsApp stop doing is background work such as the system kill the process. When I open it everything works well, instant messages with screen on and off

Comment: The OP in this [thread](https://uk.community.huawei.com/apps-39/whatsapp-notification-problems-5340) also had the same issue as you and it was solved by going to «Setting--> battery optemization --> select "all apps" on the little arrow and go to Whatsapp and select " Not allowed"». There is another solution also on that thread. I know you wrote about battery optimization but try once more, you never know.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Already tried this way and already read this post, anyway thnaks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue here with P10 - WhatsApp would not receive until opened or at least running in the background. Now it receives even if closed. I solved it by:

Settings > Search for setting > Ignore battery optimisation

If by 'Allowed' apps you don't see Whatsapp, click on the corner triangle for 'All apps', search for Whatsapp and 'Allow'

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with late or no notifications showing up, eg for Snapchat, Messenger.

> It is called PowerGenie and it kills all apps that are not on its whitelist. You cannot add custom apps on their pre-defined whitelist. This means there is no other way to fix proper app functionality on Huawei than uninstalling PowerGenie.

https://dontkillmyapp.com/huawei

Basically you can remove PowerGenie without root using ADB:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.huawei.powergenie
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.huawei.android.hwaps
```

After I removed those packages I receive notifications 100% of the time for all my apps, just how it should be (and with no impact to battery life that I can see).